# (How) Can I define my own placement settings for labels?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, labeling

Is it possible to define my own Placement settings for my labels?

[image: Placement properties]

The predefined ones are not bad, but I would need a few more of my own design. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Arc10.1 I would suggest you switch to the Maplex engine which gives you much more control over label placement.

[image]

In the Label Manager Window  select the properties option (1 in image below) to get the Placement Properties window and select the Options for user defined zones (2) to define where your labels are placed.

[image]

There are numerous other options that will give you control over label placement using the Maplex Engine, see [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Maplex_Label_Engine_placement_properties_for_advanced_labeling/00s800000073000000/) for details.

Alternatively you can convert your labels to annotation and manually move them for the required placement.